# Where are funds sent when calling decreaseLiquidity()?

Tags: uniswap

I'm trying to figure out where my funds are sent when I call the decreaseLiquidity() function.

I tried reading the docs and watching YouTube videos.

Answer (score 0):

It is sent to the owner. [check this example on docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/providing-liquidity/decrease-liquidity)

> This example assumes the contract already has possession of the
> position NFT, and requires the calling address to be the same address
> that deposited the position NFT to our contract.